# Validate an Azure idToken in Node.js

Tags: node.js, jwt, azure-active-directory

I am having trouble validating the token signature of an Azure idtoken issued by the v2 endpoint.

I have read the documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v1-id-and-access-tokens#validating-tokens), and there is also some sample code, but this refers to a languaage other than TS/JS.

Currently I my code is

```js
import {
  decode,
  verify
} from 'jsonwebtoken';

const token = 'myRand0mIdtoken...meh';
const key = 'key from -->'; // https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/discovery/v2.0/keys
console.log(
  decode(token), //works fine!
  verify(token, key) //JsonWebTokenError: invalid algorithm
);
```

How would I go about this? Decoding works, but verifying does not.

The site https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/discovery/v2.0/keys points to a JSON document containing a "keys" array. This contains multiple key objects. Of this, i have used the element in which the "kid" value matches the "kid" value in my idToken's header.

In this element there are two fields, x5t and x5c, which look like public keys. I have tried both, but no luck.

Kind regards

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found the solution.
https://nicksnettravels.builttoroam.com/post/2017/01/24/Verifying-Azure-Active-Directory-JWT-Tokens.aspx

It seems, that I have just forgotten the starting and ending lines encompassing the public key. The working format is:

-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----

*CONTENT OF x5c FIELD IN THE JSON DOC*

-----END CERTIFICATE-----